# Optimize Populating Nested Accordions

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, performance, optimization

I have three data types in a Parent -> Child -> Grandchild relationship as follows:

```
Mission -> Activity -> Project
```

where they contain the parent IDs for relation (i.e. 'Project' contains an 'Activity' ID).  I have some code I use to generate a jQuery nested accordion setup so the the user can click on a 'Mission' to see related 'Activity's, and can then click on an 'Activity' to see the related 'Project's.

The code I have takes about six seconds from hitting the page to grab the data from the database and then populating the page.  This is far too long and would like to optimize my code in anyway possible.  Using miniprofiler (miniprofiler.com) I can see it makes 131 calls to the database with a lot duplicate calls but I'm sure why.

Any help you can give me is greatly appreciated!

LINQ query I use to get all the data and organize it:

```
public IEnumerable<MissionWithActivities> GetTierTree()
{
var q = from mission in _context.tMissions
        join activity in _context.tActivities on mission.id equals activity.missionId
        join project in _context.tDefaultEventTypes on activity.id equals project.activityId
        where !project.isRemoved && project.defaultCategoryId == 4
        orderby mission.id, activity.id, mission.name
        select new DefaultEventType(project.tierLevel.TryParseEnum<GanttType>(GanttType.Unknown), DefaultCategoryRepository.CreateFrom(project.tDefaultCategory))
        {
            AllowNumericSuffix = project.allowNumericSuffix,
            AttachMilestoneMoniker = project.attachMilestoneMoniker,
            Description = project.description,
            Id = project.id,
            IsReadOnly = project.isReadOnly,
            IsSticky = project.isSticky,
            Name = project.name,
            Sid = project.sid,
            Style = project.style.TryParseEnum<GanttElementStyle>(GanttElementStyle.Unknown),
            TimeStamp = project.createdDT,
            UpdatedTimeStamp = project.updatedDT,
            Activity = new Activity { Id = activity.id, Name = activity.name, Mission = new Mission { Id = mission.id, Name = mission.name } }
        };
var q2 = q.GroupBy(
    e => e.Activity.Mission.Id,
    (mid, events) => new MissionWithActivities
    {
        Mission = events.First().Activity.Mission,
        Activities = events.GroupBy(
            e => e.Activity.Id,
            (aid, events2) => new ActivityWithEvents
            {
                Activity = events2.First().Activity,
                Events = events2
            })
    });
return q2.ToList();
```

}

Code-behind I use to initially populate a datalist and then the nested accordions:

```
public void SetTierTree(IEnumerable<MissionWithActivities> tierList)
{
dlMission.DataSource = tierList;
dlMission.DataBind();
}
public void dlMission_ItemDataBound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
DataListItem item = e.Item;
MissionWithActivities mwa = (MissionWithActivities)item.DataItem;
var dlActivity = (DataList)item.FindControl("dlActivity");
dlActivity.DataSource = mwa.Activities;
dlActivity.DataBind();
var i = 0;
foreach (var project in mwa.Activities)
{
    DataListItem pItem = dlActivity.Items[i];
    var lbCreateNewProject = (LinkButton)pItem.FindControl("lbCreateNewProject");
    lbCreateNewProject.CommandArgument = project.Activity.Id.ToString();
    var dlProject = (DataList)pItem.FindControl("dlProject");
    dlProject.DataSource = project.Events;
    dlProject.DataBind();
    i++;
    var j = 0;
    foreach (var data in project.Events)
    {
        DataListItem lblItem = dlProject.Items[j];
        var lbEditProject = (LinkButton)lblItem.FindControl("lbEditProject");
        var lbRemoveProject = (LinkButton)lblItem.FindControl("lbRemoveProject");
        lbEditProject.CommandArgument = data.Id.ToString();
        lbRemoveProject.CommandArgument = data.Id.ToString();
        j++;
    }
}
}
```

This is the .aspx page with the jQuery (I didn't remove the .net so it won't run) but I wanted to include the code for your perusal:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("html").addClass("js");
        $(".row").mouseover(function () { $(this).addClass("over"); }).mouseout(function () { $(this).removeClass("over"); });
        $('h5').click(function () { $(this).prev(".heading_add").toggle(); });
        $(".row:even").addClass("alt");
        $.fn.accordion.defaults.container = false;
        $(function () {
            $("#acc1").accordion({
                el: ".h",
                head: "h4, h5",
                next: "div",
                initShow: "none"
            });
            $("html").removeClass("js");
        });
    });
<div id="main">
        <ul id="acc1" class="accordion">
        <asp:DataList ID="dlMission" runat="server" style="width:600px;">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <h4><%# Eval("Mission.Name") %></h4>
                <div class="inner">
                    <ul>
                    <asp:DataList ID="dlActivity" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCreateNewProject" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="heading_add" runat="server" Text="[ + ] Add New Project Type" OnCommand="lbCreateNewProject_OnCommand" />
                          <h5><%# Eval("Activity.Name") %></h5>
                          <div class="inner">
                          <asp:DataList ID="dlProject" runat="server">
                          <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="row">
                              <%# Eval("Name") %><div class="action_buttons"><asp:LinkButton ID="lbEditProject" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Edit" OnCommand="lbEditProject_OnCommand" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lbRemoveProject" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnCommand="lbRemoveProject_OnCommand" /></div><br />
                            </div>
                          </ItemTemplate>
                          </asp:DataList>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

For the curious I am using the jQuery.nestedAccordion.js plugin to do this.

Comment: Rather than making 131 DB calls just pull all of the data down in one call, and then build up your tree by querying an in-memory data structure.

Comment: @Servy Are the 131 DB calls coming from my LINQ statement?  I'm guessing that maybe every time I use LINQ it hits the database again, but I don't know enough to be sure.  Does that sound correct?

Comment: Since you said, `" I can see it makes 131 calls to the database with a lot duplicate calls but **I'm sure why**."` apparently you're already sure why it's happening and don't need help with that.

Comment: @Servy Sorry, I should be more clear.  My team installed a profiler plugin yesterday called 'Mini Profiler'.  That's what is telling me it is making so many calls.  When I step through the code I don't see that at all, it just takes about 6-7s to generate.  The LINQ statement only grabs about 2000 records and organizes them and I don't think that should slow it down this much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the main cause of the slowness I was experiencing had to do with the way LINQ works.  My main issue was this in the LINQ query:

```
DefaultCategoryRepository.CreateFrom(project.tDefaultCategory)
```

The CreateFrom function was causing LINQ to grab all data associated with DefaultCategory which was extensive.  I was unaware that LINQ would grab every relationship all the way down the tree and return it whether it was being used or not.  You can read about it here for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx

MiniProfiler still says a duplicate call is being made 131 times, but I think that has to do with the way .Net runs things, if I step through the code it only hits the query once so still working that part out.

Hope this helps someone!